# How to pass Calendar param as input to a rest service?

Tags: rest, date, jax-rs, jboss7.x, resteasy

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
@POST
@Path("/MyPath")
@Produces("text/xml")
@RolesAllowed({"user"})
public Output myMethod (@QueryParam("itemId") long ItemId, 
                                    @QueryParam("plannedstartdate") Calendar plannedStartDate, 
                                    @QueryParam("plannedreturndate") Calendar plannedReturnDate)
```

I am using JBoss AS7. As far as I understan, resteasy is integrated into JBoss AS7. I am able to run simple rest services.

The only documentation I found about passing dates is at the link :
http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/StringConverter.html#StringParamUnmarshaller

I am not able to follow this and fix the issue as the instructions are not clear.
When I try to create an annotation DateFormat as given in the example, it does not recognize StringParamUnmarshaller. I don't know where to get it from. If resteasy is already integrated into JBoss AS7, is this not supposed to be recognized?

My pom.xml has the following dependency:

```
  <!-- Import the JAX-RS API, we use provided scope as the API is included 
     in JBoss AS 7 -->
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
     <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

The calls to this method fail as the String to Calendar conversion does not happen. I dont want to pass String instead of Calendar as there are other clients that make java call directly. Can anyone help with how I can pass dates to Rest Calls?

Thanks
Veer

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What error/exception do you receive?

Comment: I apologize. I just updated the question in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is resolved. See the following code.

Create an Annotation class `CalendarFormat.java`:

```java
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@StringParameterUnmarshallerBinder(CalendarFormatter.class)
public @interface CalendarFormat {
    String value();
}
```

Add a class `CalendarFormatter.java`:

```java
public class CalendarFormatter implements StringParameterUnmarshaller<Calendar> {
    private SimpleDateFormat formatter;

    public void setAnnotations(Annotation[] annotations) {
        CalendarFormat format = FindAnnotation.findAnnotation(annotations, CalendarFormat.class);
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format.value());
    }

    public Calendar fromString(String str) {
        try {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(formatter.parse(str));
            return cal;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Add to POM

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Change the method signature to use the annotation

```java
@POST
@Path("/MyPath")
@Produces("text/xml")
@RolesAllowed({"user"})
public Output myMethod(@QueryParam("itemId") long ItemId,            
        @QueryParam("plannedstartdate") @CalendarFormat("MM-dd-yyyy") Calendar plannedStartDate, 
        @QueryParam("plannedreturndate") @CalendarFormat("MM-dd-yyyy") Calendar plannedReturnDate)
```

That's it.

Comment: Be aware that this is RESTeasy specific trick, non-compliant with JAX-RS.

Comment: NOTE: I ran into thread-safety issues using this approach with RESTEasy v2.3.1. It seems that RESTEasy creates `StringParameterUnmarshaller` instances during deployment, associates them to their resource methods + parameters, and re-uses them for all requests. I employed a `ThreadLocal` to address the issue.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to use [`java.util.Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) as an argument of `@QueryParam`, because it doesn't have a one-arg constructor that accepts `String`. The only option you have is to introduce a new class `QueryCalendar`, which will have one-arg constructor and will return `Calendar` (or inherit it).

More information about who can be an argument: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html